# is there any way for rundeck opensource to trigger jobs at failed workflow step?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, devops, rundeck

Do we have any plugin or is there any way to allow the jobs to resume execution at failed workflow step?

If my job 1 and job 2 got passed, then job 3 have to trigger.If job 1 got passed and job 2 got failed and when we fix it for job 2 and triggered it manually and if it got passes, then job 3 should know the job 2 got passes and job 1 previous state is passed.then job3 should automatically trigger. Do we have any plugin or a way to do this for rundeck opensource?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to attach an [error handler](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/job-workflows.html#error-handlers) on your step (in your case [job reference step](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/node-steps/builtin.html#job-reference-step)), that error handler calls another job, I leave a basic example:

RemediationJob (the job that must be called if any `ParentJob` job reference fails through error handler):

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>67c56627-9dbd-4ad2-b6c1-04436ab3d0b2</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>RemediationJob</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <fileExtension>.sh</fileExtension>
        <script><![CDATA[echo "fixing..."
echo "fixed! try run the job again"]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
        <scriptinterpreter>/bin/bash</scriptinterpreter>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>67c56627-9dbd-4ad2-b6c1-04436ab3d0b2</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

JobA:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>5d19ea42-0431-4a68-a061-623f498222f6</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>ChildA</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <exec>echo "hi"</exec>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>5d19ea42-0431-4a68-a061-623f498222f6</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

JobB (with an intentional error on the step):

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>00f5aaa5-5726-4f65-86a3-2a3c404bff08</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>ChildB</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <exec>eco "hi"</exec>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>00f5aaa5-5726-4f65-86a3-2a3c404bff08</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

ParentJob (which calls JobA and JobB and uses error handler on any job reference step)

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>c2e0a05e-4fdd-4c33-9b4e-c9109d3667c6</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>ParentJob</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <errorhandler>
          <jobref name='RemediationJob' nodeStep='true'>
            <uuid>67c56627-9dbd-4ad2-b6c1-04436ab3d0b2</uuid>
          </jobref>
        </errorhandler>
        <jobref name='ChildA' nodeStep='true'>
          <uuid>5d19ea42-0431-4a68-a061-623f498222f6</uuid>
        </jobref>
      </command>
      <command>
        <errorhandler>
          <jobref name='RemediationJob' nodeStep='true'>
            <uuid>67c56627-9dbd-4ad2-b6c1-04436ab3d0b2</uuid>
          </jobref>
        </errorhandler>
        <jobref name='ChildB' nodeStep='true'>
          <uuid>00f5aaa5-5726-4f65-86a3-2a3c404bff08</uuid>
        </jobref>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>c2e0a05e-4fdd-4c33-9b4e-c9109d3667c6</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

In this example, the second job reference always fails intentionally, in that way you can see how to trigger another job if the step (job reference step in your case) fails.

Comment: Thank you @MegaDrive68k

I have dependencies jobs..Suppose If I have 9 jobs which are dependent on other jobs, Do I need to add error handler to all the parent jobs?

Comment: If Job 1 and Job 2 got pass, Job 5 will trigger.


If Job 3 failed and Job 4 got passed, Job 6 will trigger.


If Job 5 and Job 6 got passed, Job 7 will trigger.


If Job 7 and Job 8 got passed, Job 9 will trigger


If  job 8 has failure...hence job 9 not gonna run..In order to run job 9 , job 7, 8 must should have pass situation...

It should capture the previous run status of dependent jobs

is rundeck has ability to have sequence and to see whether last status of job is success or not..If it's success, it should trigger next one...

Comment: For that complex scenario, the best way is to call the jobs on some script step (from a "fake parent job" and validate the run using bash variables, check the script and the job definition on the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64592042/10426011 (On Rundeck Enterprise you only need to design a Ruleset Strategy Workflow: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/workflow-strategies/ruleset.html)

Comment: Yes, we have these dependency to the jobs and the main ask is 

If my job 1 got passed, job  2 got failed, my job3 won't run...
I will go and fix my job 2 manually. re-run it.

Now it's success, then job 3 should automatically understand, now job 1 last status is pass, job 2 just passed and now job 3 should automatically trigger...

The same logic for other jobs too..

We need to see if rundeck has ability to have sequence and to see whether last status success or not..If it's success, it should trigger next one...

Comment: It should capture the previous run status of dependent jobs, see whether it's meeting condition or not

Comment: You can get the status via API call/RD CLI (as the previous link, on "fake parent job" script step) check this (on that scrip step you can design any behavior in case of receiving failed status): https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/6624#issuecomment-728109181

Comment: Thank you @MegaDrive68k. 

I don't want to get the status manually...
If my job 1 got passed, job 2 got failed...I'll fix 2nd job manually and re-run it..Now it got passed...

Then my job 3 has to know that job 1 already passed earlier, now job 2 got passed. Job 3 should trigger automatically..I don't want to run manually


Can we connect once?

Comment: I see but that script is to put it on a Rundeck job (inline script), not for run manually ;-) the idea is to run the workflow on a parent job and the script "takes the decision" like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58808033/10426011. Of course, the easiest way is to use Ruleset Enterprise feature.